# How do you stop Blender from looking for an image texture?

Tags: texturing

I have an image texture I'm not using anymore, but Blender keeps the filepath and keeps showing errors, saying it can't find the texture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the textuures are really not used, you can find them in the outliner > orphan data

[image]

they are "orphan" because they have no object or anything that uses them (quite an amazing naming scheme hahaha)

Then you will find a "purge" button,
this will "purge" or remove all the orphans (sounds wrong I know)

[image]

Then, all of the unused materials will be removed from the blend.file

or you can do this to, go to file > clean up > and remove all unused data blocks

[image]